# Non-Parametric statistics Finding distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I didn't understand this one question in my book , I looked at the k out of n system but didnt get the method in order to solve

Find distribution for n out of k system reliability

Answer (score 0):

X(t) is the number of components that are working at t. [X(t) >= k] is the event "the system is working".
X(t) is Binomial(n, 1 - F(t)), where F is the life distribution.
[X(t) >= k] is equivalent to [T_(n-k+1) > t], where T_(k) is the kth order statistic of the lifetimes.

Comment: https://ibb.co/NFSpQnp

Comment: Does this make sense to you , I honestly never vet anything similar to this